# NVDA is not reading aria-label for button

Tags: html, accessibility, nvda

I am trying to get my app to adhere to accessibility standards. I have a dynamic amount of buttons being added based off a list of data. I couldn't get NVDA to read the aria-label's for the buttons. So I tried adding a simple button, like:

```
 <button aria-label="A button to upload" id="uploadBtn">Upload</button>
```

When I hover over using NVDA, it just simply says "Upload".
So then I try to add a hidden label with the for property linking to my button like:

```
 <label for="uploadBtn" class="hidemefromUsers">An upload button for required docs</label>
 <button aria-label="A button to upload" id="uploadBtn">Upload</button>


.hidemefromUsers {
  position: absolute;
  left: -99em;
  height: 0;
}
```

Again, when I hover over using nvda, it only says "Upload". I've tried in chrome, firefox and edge. All have the same results. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here? My total validator is complaining I'm not using unique labels, but I can't get it to read my aria-label property. Any ideas? thanks

Comment: You say *"hover"*, so you're using a mouse?  While there are some users that use a screen reader and also a mouse, the majority of screen reader users are keyboard users. Not that mouse hover shouldn't be supported, but I wouldn't prioritize that as a test case. What happens when you TAB to the button? It should read the `aria-label`. You should turn off "mouse tracking" in NVDA. Go into settings (Ins+n, preferences, settings) then navigate to "mouse" in the left navigation. Uncheck the "mouse tracking" checkbox. Then test with NVDA using the TAB key.

Comment: It looks like this is a known problem, https://github.com/nvaccess/nvda/issues/12047, and was also asked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75064724/accessibility-aria-label-not-being-read-on-hover/75107868#75107868

Answer (score 0):

Your are talking about hover, so I assume you are moving the mouse over the button. Here is your error.

When you use the screen reader to read what's under the mouse, it actually reads what's under the mouse, i.e. the text really visible if there is some text visible, rather than the accessible name overridden by your label.
This is quite simple to understand: partially sighted people are looking for the text actually displayed if there is one, rather than any alternative not displayed at all on the screen.
Imagine if the screen reader were reading the accessible name, i.e. your label in this case. Partially sighted people would get something different from their eyes and from their ears, which is, of course, extremely confusing.

Do the same experiment, but only use the keyboard now. Completely blind people don't use the mouse at all.
In this case, the accessible name given by your aria-label will be correctly read as you expect it when you land on the button with tab or arrow keys.

To add a little more to the fun, try a voice control software and test: which of the displayed text and overridden accessible name allow to activate the button ?
It's maybe not the one you expect. In any case, someone will end up confused and will say that your app doesn't work.

This leads to a rather simple principle: **don't use aria-label / aria-labelledby to replace another visible readable label**, or, otherwise said, **don't override a perfectly legible label**.
These attributes are to be used **only when there is no legible text label on screen**.

If you want blind users  to have a different text than sighted users, prefer  using visually hidden text.
There are legitimate reasons to do this. It's typically needed if your label is just a text icon or an emoji.

Back to your case, avoid the aria-label version:

```
<button aria-label="blind label">visible label</button>
```

But use the visually hiddden text technique instead:

```
<button><span class="sr_only">blind label</span><span aria-hidden="true">visible label</span></button>
```

While keeping in mind that voice control software and maybe other assistive tools will react on the aria-label, possibly putting people with motor disabilities in trouble.
So, this has to be reserved in the case of text icons, emojis and the like; not to replace another text either.

To wrap up, the best advice is to choose a single unique label, which can be clear for everybody. So you will avoid all such problems. Keep it simple!

Comment: I'd also suggest using `type="button"` because the default is `type="submit"`. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button